# Excel Macro send email

Tags: email, excel, vba

i have a report that i would like to send via excel.
it will include the recipitents, subject and the information in the body. actually it could copy the cells in question.
what i did so far is create a button and assign a macro to it with this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show arg1:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3"), _
                      arg2:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E7")

End Sub
```

the problem is that this command sends the workbook as attachment.

can someone help me with the code that will allow me to do this.

thanks a million!

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a reference to the "Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library" and you can use this code as an example of what to do to build or send an email:

As it is it will just display the email without sending.  You can comment out the .display line and uncomment the .send to just send it.

```
Sub EmailFromExcel()
    On Error GoTo PROC_EXIT
    Dim OL As New Outlook.Application

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim SrcSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Set SrcSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With olMail
        .To = SrcSheet.Range("E3").Text
        .Subject = SrcSheet.Range("E7").Text
        .Body = SrcSheet.Range("E12").Text
        .Display vbModal
        '.Send
    End With

 PROC_EXIT:
    On Error GoTo 0
    OL.Quit
    Set OL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This works great, but I prefer it without OL.Quit, which closes the user's Outlook if it is open.

Comment: @HeadofCatering I prefer it without the `Dim ... As New` notation. Otherwise it seems to work well.

Comment: It's definitely up to you to make sure you instantiate Outlook properly, either by checking it it's already open using GetObject, or whatever.  The illustrative part of this code is just putting Excel values into an Outlook email.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the outlook com library; then you can copy/paste values & formatting what you need to a new sheet, then copy that into the outlook mail.